# iAd banner views on top using canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

When I use iOS 7 iAds like this, they are placed at the bottom of the screen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
```

How can I place them at the top instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way right now, if you are displaying iAds using the UIViewController additions. Have a look at the [official Apple documentation to it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/canDisplayBannerAds).

You can see that:

> Banner ads are displayed below the content.

In order to place the ads above the content, you would have to create and `ADBannerView` manually (programatically).